# Noob running xubuntu 14.04 and skype audio doesn't work

Tags: sound, xubuntu, skype

Pulseaudo recognizes my mike and headphone. I don't have any issues with listening to music or watching movies but skype just doesn't work at all. I downloaded the deb from the official website and installed it using ubuntu software centre.

I have no idea what the issue might be, please help me. None of the other responses to similar threads work. I tried all of them out.

Comment: Have you looked in Skype's audio settings and switched it to Pulse?

Comment: @robobenklein I just tried and under microphone speakers and ringing virtual device is selected. All three dropboxes have no other options. test ring and test call are both silent. :(

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution on [WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/get-sound-working-in-skype-with-ubuntu.html) -

`sudo sed -i 's/^Exec=.*/Exec=env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30 skype %U/' /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop`

The command above replaces "skype" from the Skype desktop file with "env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30 skype", this being a work-around for getting Skype to work with PulseAudio 4.0.

Comment: This didn't work. Sorry. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try installing - pavucontrol to the system and check that resolves the issue, if pavucontrol is already there, try reinstall it once and restart the Skype again.

Command to reinstall - pavucontrol

sudo apt-get install --reinstall pavucontrol,

Comment: Just did this. Not working after reboot also. My audio is perfect and pulse detects my mike. No idea what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reset Skype config running this in a terminal:
`mv .Skype/ .Skypeold`
and test after really stopping skype:
 `killall skype`
Also look this page  from Skype  [faq](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10964/how-do-i-adjust-the-sound-settings-on-my-computer-and-in-skype-for-linux?q=linux)